# How to connect a user to sockets

Tags: node.js, express, redis, socket.io, pug

I am trying to connect the user session id created with the cookie created for each user after login along with connecting it to the sockets... any direction or examples will be great... I am using nodejs, express, redis, socket.io and using mongodb for the rest of my db stuff.

Here is the code in the app.js file(But I am unsure of some of it)

```
var connect = require('connect');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
  var redis = require("redis").createClient();
  var io = require('socket.io');
  var notificationsN = io.listen(server);

app.use(express.session({
      secret: "secret sauce",
      store: new RedisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 3000, client: redis })
  }));

//Not sure if below is correct actually... need to connect it with the current user... how do i go about doing that?

notificationsN.on('connection', function(client) {
    const subscribe = redis
    subscribe.subscribe('realtime');

    subscribe.on('message', function(channel, message) {
      client.send(message);
      console.log('message received from ' + channel + " : " + message);
    });

    client.on('message', function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    });

    client.on('disconnect', function() {
      console.log('disconnecting from redis');
      subscribe.quit();
    });

  });
```

This is the client:

```
script(src='http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js')
script.
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost/3000/');

            socket.on('connect', function (data) {
                setStatus('connected');
                socket.emit('subscribe', { channel: 'realtime' });
            });

            socket.on('reconnecting', function(data) {
                setStatus('reconnecting');
            });

            socket.on('message', function(data) {
                console.log('received a message: ', data);
                addMessage(data);
            });

            function addMessage(data) {
                $('#notificationNumber').html(data);
            }

            function setStatus(msg) {
                console.log('connection status: ' + msg);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly this should be your solution: http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/